# Saving parseable string into core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I 'm developing an uitableview based application which sections and rows  numbers for different selecions are determined by the data from core data. Now i need a structure for keeping user's choice.

To be clear, its an password saving app and users can save their informations according to pre installed templates. As seen in the images below, different key value pairs, for wireless router and instant messenger selections, are shown in the table view. I keep rows information for different types in core data so that rows can be loaded dynamically according to values from core data...

[image: type][image: wireless router][image: instant messngr]

The application is for one user. User can change the values of a any row including the row in title header, "wireless router" value for example... After a user make some changes in the rows' value and click "Save" bar button at top right, a third tab will be added to below and will display this new data modified by the user.

> My question is how should i keep the new data modified by user?

My core data structure is;

[image: core data]

A solution comes in my mind is to keep values as a parseable string in a table, which is "SavedData" in image above.

What approach can be more suitable to solve what i need. Is saving key value pairs into one table as parseable string sth proper and efficient? or is there a better way.

Comment: If you just carry password, URL and Username to next page , add them to NSUSerDefaluts , And keep one flag that tells whether u logged in or logout , based on that flag , u can present logins screen (which is shown above)

Comment: This is massive overkill for `CoreData`. `CoreData` is meant as more of a database, where you'll have multiple rows under each `Entity`. Here, you may have one or two rows (depending if a user logs out and logs back in on another account), but you're introducing a lot of overhead for this. Use `NSUserDefaults`, it's not worth implementing `CoreData` for just this.

Comment: Ok, i think the question is misunderstood, i will edit it. This is no login implementation indeed.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is a versatile solution. It accepts NSArray, NSData, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSString. There are many different ways you could model this. If you expect the app to have multiple users you could store Dictionaries of usernames, passwords, url. If the use case is only one single user than something like this should work fine. Top line is to save and bottom line is to read from anywhere in the app.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:usernameTextField.text forKey:@"flickerUsername"];


NSString flickerUsername = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] object ForKey:@"flickerUsername"];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not what i am looking for, edited my question btw.